# Lightning Web component is not getting deployed from Source to Org

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

Lightning Web component is not getting deployed successfully from Source to Org.
Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include the screenshot... Could you please [edit] your question? Also, if it's just text, please just copy-paste the **text** itself, since it is far easier to read and work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you have a component in aura/helloWorld. You would need to delete that bundle from the server first, or rename one of them. You cannot have an Aura bundle and LWC bundle with the same name.